# No module named 'flask_restful'

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I have installed flask_restful using the command

```
pip install flask_restful
```

it works with sublimetext but not with pycharm. The environment I am using is python3 with anaconda on both IDEs

Comment: Your `pip` command is probably for Python 2, or not related to the Anaconda Python. Try `python3 -m pip install flask_restful` for a start.

Comment: I got message : "Requirement already satisfied:"

Comment: Then you'll have to figure out within PyCharm how to change its configuration so it uses the correct Python executable.

Comment: If it works in SublimeText, try `import sys; print(sys.executable)` there and compare that to what you get in PyCharm. If they are not the same, change it in the PyCharm configuration.

Answer (score 1):

when you type in the import function in PYCharm a red lightbulb should pop up, click on it and it should give you the option to install the module to pycharm.